# Is it possible to apply for a second masters degree in a different field of study? (different department)

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions, masters

Specifically, is it possible to apply for a second masters degree in **MS&E** (management science and engineering) or statistics (**MS in statistics**) after a masters degree in **computer science**?

How will my application be treated compared to other applicants? (with a bachelors degree)

Comment: I recommend that people usually shouldn't go masters hopping unless they have tons of money to spare. Computer Science is close enough to the fields you mention that if you self study those fields you can get jobs designed for people with an MS in statistics and MS&E. But to answer your question masters programs are cash cows you will be let in if the admissions committee feels you can successfully finish their program.

Answer (score 2):

It's always possible to *apply*, whether you will be *accepted* is a different matter. The best thing to do is to speak to the academic who is the programme director (or similar title), explain that you are interested in applying for the course and see what they say. They will know what the general rules are as well as being able to provide specific guidance. The fact that your current masters degree is in a related subject (different department, but probably the same faculty) means it should be considered relevant.

I applied for a MA in Classics & Ancient History after getting a BSc in Computer Science, and then went back to do an MPhil in Computer Science, so it is possible to move subjects.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about your school, but in my school, the title of your degree doesn't really matter much PROVIDING THAT YOU HAVE SUFFICIENT ACADEMIC BACKGROUND in the discipline that you are interested in. For instance, if I am a BSc in Statistics grad, and if I have taken significant number of Computing Science courses, then given that my GPA is high enough, I will be admitted to the Computing Science department for their MSc program.